# using array_filter after another array_filter to exclude a word(s)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, array-filter

what i have is this

```
foreach ($array["Book"] as $abeBooks) {

$abeResult[$i] = array(
            'itemCondition' => $abeBooks['itemCondition'],
            'isbn13' =>$abeBooks['isbn13'],
            'listingPrice' =>$abeBooks['listingPrice'],
            'Link' =>$abeBooks['listingUrl'],
            'sellerRating'=>$abeBooks['sellerRating'],
            'vendorDescription'=>$abeBooks['vendorDescription'],
            'totalListingPrice'=>$abeBooks['totalListingPrice'],

);


$i++; }

$conditions = array("Fine",  "Very Good","Good", "New");

$resulted = array_filter($abeResult, function($book) use ($conditions) {
return in_array($book['itemCondition'], $conditions);
});


 usort($resulted, function($a, $b) {
 if ($a['listingPrice'] < $b['listingPrice']) return -1;
 if ($a['listingPrice'] > $b['listingPrice']) return 1;
   return 0;
});

$finalresult = reset($resulted);
```

$finalresult returns an array with the lowest price only including $conditions. but i need to add before usort portion an additional filter..
the filter would be

```
$international="nternational" (like one would with a query like %nternational%)
```

so it would not be an array filter (but it could be if it had to) it would sort using $resulted['vendorDescription'] but if needed or easier it could sort first before the array filter---

**just to be clear i want to EXCLUDE any result that has nternational in vendorDesription.**

Comment: Can you use `preg_grep()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to

> EXCLUDE any result that has `nternational` in `vendorDescription`

then you can modify `array_filter` callback as:

```
$resulted = array_filter($abeResult, function($book) use ($conditions) {
    return in_array($book['itemCondition'], $conditions) 
        && strpos($book['vendorDescription'], 'nternational') === false;
});
```